# Veeam Marks Data Tape as Cleaning Tape

Tags: backup, tape, veeam

Today I ran into the issue described on this [Veeam Community Forum post](https://forums.veeam.com/tape-f29/tape-with-data-marked-as-cleaning-tape-t30545.html). Under specific circumstances, Veeam inadvertently marks a legitimate tape as a cleaning tape, removing it entirely from view in VBR console. There's no user-accessible way to remove it from the catalog, nor does erasing, re-scanning, or inventorying the tape have any effect.

**Symptoms:**

You will see the following entries in your logs:

```
:: TapeDrive alert: The tape drive is due for routine cleaning:.  Wait for the current operation to finish. Then use a cleaning cartridge. Check the tape drive user manual for device specific cleaning instructions. 
:: TapeDrive alert: The last cleaning cartridge used in the tape drive has worn out:.  Discard the worn out cleaning cartridge. Wait for the current operation to finish. Then use a new cleaning cartridge. 
:: Marking tape <TapeName> as a cleaning cartridge
```

And you will notice a slot in your tape library has magically disappeared. The missing slot will correspond with the location of the tape Veeam believes is a cleaning cartridge.

[image: Veeam Tape List]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to happen when there is an automatic cleaning process and the specified cleaning tape has expired. The next tape that enters the drive seems to get marked as a cleaning tape. There may be other scenarios that cause this, but the solution remains the same.

**Please note that this is intended as an emergency fix only. Modifying the Veeam database on your own is not a supported action. While this worked just fine for me, this may break your installation. Veeam support may not be able/willing to assist.**

Open SQL Server Management Studio and connect to the Veeam database. You will need the server name & instance name. You may also need to enable TCP/IP for the instance in order to connect from a remote system, as it is not always enabled by default. This is outside the scope of this Q/A.

To get a list of media marked as cleaning tapes, issue the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT [barcode], [name], [cleaner]
FROM [VeeamBackup].[dbo].[Tape.tape_mediums]
WHERE [cleaner] = 1;
```

This should give you results similar to the following. Note the first tape listed is an actual cleaning tape, and follows the naming convention specified by the LTO specification for a universal cleaning cartridge. The second result is our missing tape.

[image: SSMS Query Result]

Now we just have fix this. A simple update to the cleaner property is all that's needed. You can use any property to select the appropriate tape; I used barcode since I know they're all unique in my environment.

```
UPDATE [VeeamBackup].[dbo].[Tape.tape_mediums]
SET [cleaner] = 0
WHERE [barcode] = 'S16023L5';
```

And voilà, your tape is once again visible! The change should take effect almost immediately in the VBR console.